# Angular 11 + Angular Material router navigation opens page at bottom by default?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular11

*** Update - I have added some links to a StackBlitz that replicates this issue. It appears to be an issue with the  being nested inside my . If I remove it from there the issue goes away, but then my material controls don't work. Here is a StackBlitz that demonstrates this issue. On the home page scroll all the way down and click the "About Me" button. https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-haakon

+++ Original Question +++

On my homepage ([www.haakon.io](http://www.haakon.io)) I have several sections, one of the sections near the bottom of the home page has a link to my food page. When you click the foodie link on the page, the food page is correctly navigated to, but the browser is scrolled to the same location as where the link was clicked on the home page, the bottom of that page. Here is the link I'm using:

```
<p>Go to my <a [routerLink]="['/food']" >foodie</a> page.
```

I did see several issues on here that seemed like they might be similar and I tried to resetPosition(); from both the router activates and when that didn't work, I tried to do the same from AfterViewInit, which also didn't work. Here is the HTML from the app.component:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="resetPosition();"></router-outlet>
```

This is the typescript component:

```
  @ViewChild("mainDiv", {read: ElementRef, static:false})
  mainDiv: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementById("mainDiv") as HTMLDivElement;

  resetPosition() {
    this.mainDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  }
```

This is a very strange behavior that I haven't noticed in any other versions of Angular.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this -

1. Use following code in your resetPosition() method -

   window.scrollTo(0,0)
2. You can use {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'} in router configuration like this -

   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions)

Comment: She is right, use `{scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}` it will be aplied to all routes.

Comment: Tried these solutions and they did not work for me. I think I may have discovered why after creating some StackBlitz examples. It looks like using Angular Material is the issue.